# How to choose what server technology stack to use for a mobile application?

Tags: java, mobile, server-side

I want to prototype a server application to support a mobile application. But how do I start? Where do I start looking for information? It seems something that supports REST services would be the most flexible. But what exactly is this "something"?

I have Java background, but I'm looking for actual library/tool/technology recommendations, something that's pretty easy to pick up (and something that can support web applications should a future need arise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, writing RESTful services is the best option. (Perhaps with OAuth authentication)

There are a couple of rest frameworks in Java, notably:

- spring-mvc
- Jersey, RestEasy (JAX-RS implementations)

Evaluate them and see which one you like most.